# I am trying to validate user input using JavaScript. I would like to validate that the user has input their the title of their course correctly

Tags: javascript, validation

Sell/Trade Textbook Form - 'Course Title' Field

- Check that it begins with a letter(s), followed by a number(s), followed by a space, and followed by a letter(s) or number(s).

  1. Example: IS448 Markup and Scripting Languages
  2. Example: CTP150 Computer Science 1

This is what I have so far:

```
(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/);
```

but it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: tip: you can try your regex with this https://regex101.com/r/xBjMVF/1, its an example of henry's regex

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$
```